# Can I repair Win XP MBR using WIn 7 CD?

Tags: windows, multi-boot, mbr

I have a dual boot machine (ubuntu 12.04 and xp sp3) and now I want to get rid of ubuntu.
After searching over the internet I found that I should first remove the grub (by fixing the MBR) so that the system directly boots into windows and then the ubuntu partitions can be deleted/formatted without trouble.

The problem is that I have a Windows 7 installation CD. I was wondering if I could use it for this purpose? Is is mandatory to use a win xp CD?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Boot into the Windows 7 installation CD, and when you reach the screen with a "Start Install" button, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> and a command prompt should show up.

Now you should identify the drive that boots Windows (see below). Let's say it's `X:`, for example. You would execute the following command(s):

```
bootsect.exe /nt52 X:
bootsect.exe /nt52 X: /mbr
```

Now, the MBR should be restored to a Windows XP-compatible (`NTLDR`) format.

---

To identify the drive that boots Windows, you would type the following command first:

```
notepad.exe
```

After that, a Notepad window should appear. Now click "File"->"Open" to show an Open File dialog. Go to "Computer" and you should be able to identify the drive letter of the boot drive according to the size and/or drive label.

If you still can't identify the drive, you can first select to show All Files, then look for `NTLDR` and `boot.ini` on the root of the drives.

I myself had done this a few times before.

---

**DISCLAIMER: The content contained in this answer is for reference only. I am *NOT* responsible if this answer causes any hard drive failures, data loss, loss of property, injuries, or even deaths. Remember, all actions involving hard drives are extremely dangerous. For every single (nano)second the drive is powered, it is one step closer to its own death and data might be lost from it. So if you are absolutely worried, do NOT use a hard drive at all.**

Comment: are you sure this is going to work 100 % because i have some important data in the windows installation

Comment: @MayankSharma No. See my disclaimer.

Comment: http://neosmart.net/blog/2007/bootsectexe-modifies-the-bootsector-not-the-mbr/

Comment: @MayankSharma We're talking about using the Windows 7 DVD for XP here, but you'd remind me of the extra command that I've done.

Comment: Hi Alvin! Does this work in the opposite direction? I.E. to use a WinXP cd to repair a Win7 mbr? Thanks!